# Returning multiple images in SQL query

Tags: 7, database

I have two images I need to return in my custom module's SQL. It works with returning just 1, but when I add another it shows both as blank and dpm($row) shows the field as NULL. I've double checked all the mappings in the SQL and they should be right, although I AM suspicious of this line I wrote:

```
LEFT JOIN {file_managed} AS fm ON 
(fdfti.field_taxonomy_icon_fid=fm.fid 
AND fdfcm.field_costs_money_fid=fm.fid)
```

The idea is I want to return each image value if it exists (both if both exist, and just the first one - icon - if only it exists). It works if I just join in the fdfti.field_taxonomy_icon_fid.

Is this allowed with the 'AND' operation?

Also, the following is how I'm transcribing the returned results for the 'uri' field:

```
$icon = image_style_url('thumbnail', $row['uri']);
$dollar = image_style_url('thumbnail', $row['uri']);
```

Note: If I remove the $dollar variable and just have the $icon variable set and remove the AND clause from the above SQL, well then $row['uri'] returns the image. But when I have both neither show up.

Thoughts?

Per request, the entire SQL statement is as posted:

```
$result = db_query("
SELECT n.title, n.nid, n.status, n.type,
  fdfty.field_type_value, fdfi.entity_id, fdfi.field_icon_tid, fdfti.entity_id, 
  fdfti.field_taxonomy_icon_fid, fm.uri, fm.fid, ua.source, ua.alias, 
  el.field_experience_level_value, fdb.body_value, fdfr.field_role_value, 
  fdft.field_topics_value, fdfed.field_event_dates_value, fdfed.field_event_dates_value2 
FROM {node} AS n 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_type} AS fdfty ON n.nid=fdfty.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_icon} AS fdfi ON n.nid=fdfi.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_taxonomy_icon} AS fdfti ON fdfi.field_icon_tid=fdfti.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_price} AS fdfp ON n.nid=fdfp.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_costs_money} AS fdfcm ON fdfp.field_price_tid=fdfcm.entity_id
LEFT JOIN {file_managed} AS fm ON (fdfti.field_taxonomy_icon_fid=fm.fid AND 
  fdfcm.field_costs_money_fid=fm.fid) 
LEFT JOIN {url_alias} AS ua ON CONCAT('node/', nid)=source 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_experience_level} AS el ON n.nid=el.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_body} AS fdb ON n.nid=fdb.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_role} AS fdfr ON n.nid=fdfr.entity_id
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_topics} AS fdft ON n.nid=fdft.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_event_dates} AS fdfed ON n.nid=fdfed.entity_id 
WHERE n.status=:status AND n.type=:resource AND (fdfty.field_type_value=:webinar 
OR fdfty.field_type_value=:workshoptraining OR fdfty.field_type_value=:conference) 
AND el.field_experience_level_value=:level AND fdfr.field_role_value=:role 
AND fdft.field_topics_value=:topic AND ((fdfed.field_event_dates_value IS NULL) 
OR (fdfed.field_event_dates_value >= CURRENT_DATE())) GROUP BY n.nid, n.title 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN fdfty.field_type_value='1' THEN 0 WHEN fdfty.field_type_value='2' 
THEN 1 WHEN fdfty.field_type_value = '3' THEN 2 END, fdfed.field_event_dates_value, 
  n.title", array(':status' => '1', ':resource' => 'resource', ':webinar' => '1', 
  ':workshoptraining' => '2', ':conference' => '3', ':level' => $level, ':role' => $role, 
  ':topic' => $topic));
```

Comment: You will need to include your full query to debug. It's also possible you could use `EntityFieldQuery` instead.

Comment: @David Thomas Ok, I Posted it (see above). It's a big statement and I tried to format it to make it more readable...it's a bit better, but not perfect. Like I said though the statement works before I added in the lines about field_data_field_price and field_data_field_costs_money and used the 'And' phrasing with the fm field. So lines 10 - 13 are what is giving me trouble. And then figuring out how to reference the fields (which have associated images (uri is the column in the db) for the file_managed field in lines 12 and 13.

Comment: Have you looked at using [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)? It is made to query for entities based on field conditions etc.. and takes care of all those joins for you.

Comment: @David Thomas This looks very promising. Actually I was looking for this very documentation a few weeks ago for something else. Thanks for sharing this invaluable resource!